# Is there a way to load Angular2 app to its root tag on call/event?

Tags: javascript, angular

Right now, Angular2 loads the application to the html root tag when the page loads. I need a functionality that will somehow call like `Angular2.load()` or something to start the loading of the app on call and not automatically when the page loads.

Comment: This depends on why you want to do this. You may likely to postpone loading of entire app, not just bootstrapping (that's where `System.import` and relevant answer may help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we ended up doing is

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'bootstrapMyApp', {
    value: function() {
        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    }
});
```

in our production file.

So invoking `window.bootstrapMyApp()` would load the Angular App.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command when you want to start app

```
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

Comment: It says `System is not defined`

Comment: this is only when using `system.js` to compile `Angular2`. might as weel explore angular2 cycle first.. before posting. .it would be helpful